# Scraping data and combining it to form a single variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

My goal is to scrape the sizes and the data-sku from this site, and combine the data for each  `sizing` and `sizeID` into individual single variable.
The [site](https://m.jdsports.com.sg/product/red-jordan-air-1-mid/16139989_jdsportssg/stock/) has a total of 3 sizes 8.5-9.5, each size having its own unique data-sku. How would I combine the data for `sizing` and `sizeID` into each a variable with 3 sets of values.

Ideal Results

```
variable for sizing = 8.5,9,9.5
variable for sizeID = 16139989_jdsportssg.2905173,16139989_jdsportssg.2905175,16139989_jdsportssg.2905176
```

Current Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#scraping the for the product size ID
stocksource = requests.get('https://m.jdsports.com.sg/product/red-jordan-air-1-mid/16139989_jdsportssg/stock/').text
stockpage = BeautifulSoup(stocksource, "lxml")

for size in stockpage.select('#productSizeStock > button'):
    global sizing
    global sizeID
    sizing = size.text
    sizeID = size['data-sku']
    print(sizing)
    print(sizeID)
```

Also not too sure why but if you run my code now, the sizing results seem to have a lot of spaces in the beginning and the end. Anyways any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary, where keys are size and values are SKUs:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

stocksource = requests.get(
    "https://m.jdsports.com.sg/product/red-jordan-air-1-mid/16139989_jdsportssg/stock/"
).text
stockpage = BeautifulSoup(stocksource, "lxml")

out = {}
for button in stockpage.select("#productSizeStock > button"):
    out[button.get_text(strip=True)] = button["data-sku"]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'8.5': '16139989_jdsportssg.2905173', 
 '9': '16139989_jdsportssg.2905175', 
 '9.5': '16139989_jdsportssg.2905176', 
 '10': '16139989_jdsportssg.2905179'}
```

---

EDIT: To load the data to separate lists:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

stocksource = requests.get(
    "https://m.jdsports.com.sg/product/red-jordan-air-1-mid/16139989_jdsportssg/stock/"
).text
stockpage = BeautifulSoup(stocksource, "lxml")

sizes = []
skus = []
for button in stockpage.select("#productSizeStock > button"):
    sizes.append(button.get_text(strip=True))
    skus.append(button["data-sku"])

print(sizes)
print(skus)
```

Prints:

```
['8.5', '9', '9.5', '10']
['16139989_jdsportssg.2905173', '16139989_jdsportssg.2905175', '16139989_jdsportssg.2905176', '16139989_jdsportssg.2905179']
```

Comment: Kesley would there be a way that the sizes and the skus are separated?